# Alarm, Calendar,Alarm +Calendar or something else?

Tags: android

I need to write app, that will be make notifications at define date and time(for example, each 1th day of the month at 1am).This notifications must be as dialogs that user can see and choose OK(go to app) or Cancel(Cancel dialog).
What I need to use to realize repeaching events:Alarm, Calendar,Alarm +Calendar or something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` for repeating events of this nature, typically with an `RTC` alarm type to tie the alarm to a real-world time.